# Iframe in mobile browsers width goes outside of the page

Tags: html, css, mobile, iframe, browser

I have an iframe inside a web page that loads perfectly in desktop browsers.  Inside mobile browsers, the width of the content inside the iframe goes way outside of the page.  If I load the content that the iframe is loading, it looks perfect.  Does anyone know what might cause this incorrect content size in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing this in your document's `<HEAD>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

You could play with the options if you like, for instance, removing user-scalable, etc.  This should be in the document inside the iframe as well as the containing document, if you're having problems there.